# What are all the certificates mandatory to be provide while setting TLSVerifyClient option to demand

Tags: authentication, ldap, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, slapd

In my case, I had set **TLSVerifyClient** to **demand**.
I couldn't be able to establish a connection While providing TLSCACertificateFile alone.

While setting the **TLSVerifyClient** option **demand** is it mandatory to provide the following option*?

1. TLSCACertificateFile
2. TLSCertificateKeyFile
3. TLSCertificateFile

Regards,
Ram

Try,

I have set the TLSVerifyClient option to demand and trying to establish a connection with the LDAP server only with the TLSCACertificateFile certificate alone.

Expecting,

The connection needs to be established between the server and the client.

Comment: What TLSVerifyClient option? Option to what? Where's is this option documented?